# How do I shut off the out-of-date plugin notification on Chrome in OS X?

Tags: command-line, google-chrome, osx-leopard

I understand that, in order to shut off out-of-date plugin notifications, you need to add the command-line flag "allow-outdated-plugins."  Is there a way to do this on OS X that doesn't require extensive scripting or Xcode stuff?

Answer (score 2):

Open a Terminal window and paste this. Change the path if you installed Chrome somewhere else.

`'/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome' --allow-outdated-plugins`